# Given an array of strings, return the count of total instances of each character

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to aggregate data for reporting in our database, and when accessing the data it returns as an array of strings like so:

```
[
    0 => null
    1 => "1"
    2 => "1"
    3 => "1,2,3"
    4 => "2"
    5 => "2"
    6 => "3"
]
```

what I need to do is transform the array somehow so that this is the result:

```
[
    "N/A" => 1,
    "1" => 3,
    "2" => 3,
    "3" => 2,
]
```

where null values in the array are counted as "N/A" and all other values are counted distinctly like above, there are 3 1's, 3 2's, and 2 3's.

Per request, what I have tried so far is a few variations on the map() function:

```
$typeCounts = $referralsByType->map(function ($item) {
        $item = explode(',', $item);
        $item = array_filter($item);
        $item = array_count_values($item);
        $item = array_map(function ($key, $value) {
            if ($key === null) {
                $key = 'N/A';
            }
            return [$key => $value];
        }, array_keys($item), array_values($item));
        $item = array_collapse($item);
        return $item;
    });
```

I've played around with a few different variations of the above code, but it ends up giving incorrect results in a format that I didn't expect.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: @symlink I have added additional context and given my latest attempt as an example.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
 $totals = implode(',', $referralsByType);
 $totals = explode(',', $totals);
 $totals = array_count_values($totals);
```

I was overcomplicating this entire function, I just needed to take a second and step away.

Comment: That implode-explode stuff is completely superfluous, all three lines can be replaced with just `$totals = array_count_values($referralsByType);`